# D3.js donut chart... arc.centroid(d) is not influenced by d.innerRadius and d.outerRadius

Tags: d3.js, pie-chart, donut-chart

I'm creating a donut (or Piechart) and I want to place the labels just outside the area.
I've created a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/VeeTee/mA3V7/ for it.

```
arcs.append("svg:text")
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
        //this is where I want to make a translation to the outside border
        d.innerRadius = radius;
        d.outerRadius = height/2;
        return "translate(" + arc.centroid(d) +")";
    })
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .text(function(d, i) { return d.value.toFixed(2); });
```

arc.centroid(d) -> is always giving the same result (and therefore the same translation)

Answer (score 10):

Not sure what you mean by that it's always giving you the same result, but you can place the labels just outside the chart by multiplying the coordinates of the centroid by 1.5. The code is something like this.

```
.attr("transform", function(d) {
        var c = arc.centroid(d);
        return "translate(" + c[0]*1.5 +"," + c[1]*1.5 + ")";
    })
```

Updated jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/mA3V7/1/).

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply... 
But... do you know why setting
   d.innerRadius = radius;
   d.outerRadius = height/2;
in all the examples (before calling arc.centroid(d)) will make arc.centroid offset ?

Comment: Setting those values doesn't have any effect for me.

Comment: check this... http://bl.ocks.org/Guerino1/2295263
.attr("transform", function(d) { //set the label's origin to the center of the arc
        //we have to make sure to set these before calling arc.centroid
        d.outerRadius = outerRadius + 50; // Set Outer Coordinate
        d.innerRadius = outerRadius + 45; // Set Inner Coordinate
        return "translate(" + arc.centroid(d) + ")";
      })

Comment: You're setting both the inner and outer radius explicitly in the definition of `arc`, hence the changes you make in that function have no effect.

Comment: this last comment fixed my problem! I thought passing the arguments to centroid would override the base arc generator arguments but it's not the case.