# d3.js animation of a dougnut pie chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am working on an application that will be a hybrid pie chart and bubble chart - 
[image]
here is a working animation for a simple doughnut pie chart.

http://jsfiddle.net/Qh9X5/8817/

```
var svg = d3.select("body")
    .append("svg")
    .append("g")

svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "slices");
svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "labels");
svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "lines");

var width = 560,
    height = 450,
    radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2;

var pie = d3.layout.pie()
    .sort(null)
    .value(function(d) {
        return d.value;
    });

var arc = d3.svg.arc()
    .outerRadius(radius * 0.85)
    .innerRadius(radius * 0.83);

var outerArc = d3.svg.arc()
    .innerRadius(radius * 0.9)
    .outerRadius(radius * 0.9);

svg.attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");

var key = function(d){ return d.data.label; };

var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .domain(["Lorem ipsum", "dolor sit", "amet", "consectetur", "adipisicing"])
    .range(["#98abc5", "#8a89a6", "#7b6888", "#6b486b", "#a05d56"]);

function randomData (){
    var labels = color.domain();
    return labels.map(function(label){
        return { label: label, value: Math.random() }
    });
}


console.log("randomData()", randomData());
change(randomData());

d3.select(".randomize")
    .on("click", function(){
        change(randomData());
    });


function change(data) {

    /* ------- PIE SLICES -------*/
    var slice = svg.select(".slices").selectAll("path.slice")
        .data(pie(data), key);

    slice.enter()
        .insert("path")
        .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.data.label); })
        .attr("class", "slice");

    slice       
        .transition().duration(1000)
        .attrTween("d", function(d) {
            this._current = this._current || d;
            var interpolate = d3.interpolate(this._current, d);
            this._current = interpolate(0);
            return function(t) {
                return arc(interpolate(t));
            };
        })

    slice.exit()
        .remove();

};
```

[image]
http://jsfiddle.net/NYEaX/1487/
This is a static doughnut chart -- where I have calculated the mid-arcs -- but have lost the animation. So with the above sample of code -- where is it possible to obtain the arc.centroid(d)?

```
var width = 960,
    height = 500,
    radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2;

var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .range(["#98abc5", "#8a89a6", "#7b6888", "#6b486b", "#a05d56", "#d0743c", "#ff8c00"]);

var arc = d3.svg.arc()
    .outerRadius(radius - 60)
    .innerRadius(radius - 70);

var pie = d3.layout.pie()
    .sort(null)
    .value(function(d) { return d.value; });

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");


  var data = [
    {
      "group": "<5",
      "value": 1000,
      "children": [
        {
          "group": "<5",     
          "label": "Mel",
          "value": 1000,
          "totalGroupValue": 1000
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "group": "5-13",
      "value": 1000,
      "children": [
        {
          "group": "5-13",        
          "label": "Erica",
          "value": 1000,
          "totalGroupValue": 1000
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "group": "14-17",
      "value": 2000,
      "children": [
        {
          "group": "14-17",
          "label": "Jessica",
          "value": 1500,
          "totalGroupValue": 2000  
        },
        {
          "group": "14-17",
          "label": "Jill",
          "value": 500,
          "totalGroupValue": 2000  
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "group": "18-24",
      "value": 1300,
      "children": [
        {
          "group": "18-24",
          "label": "Jerry",
          "value": 500,          
          "totalGroupValue": 1300 
        },
        {
          "group": "18-24",
          "label": "Ben",
          "value": 500,
          "totalGroupValue": 1300  
        },
        {
          "group": "18-24",
          "label": "Billy",
          "value": 300,
          "totalGroupValue": 1300  
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "group": "25-44",
      "value": 1000,
      "children": [
        {
          "group": "25-44",
          "label": "Kelly",
          "value": 1000,
          "totalGroupValue": 1000
        }
      ]
    }
  ];  


  var g = svg.selectAll(".arc")
      .data(pie(data))
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "arc");

  g.append("path")
      .attr("d", arc)
      .style("fill", function(d) {
        return color(d.data.group); 
      });

  arc
    .outerRadius(radius - 10)
    .innerRadius(0);


//create zone regions

var zones = [];
g.append("circle")
  .attr("transform", function(d) {
        zones[d.data.group] = arc.centroid(d);
    return "translate(" + arc.centroid(d) + ")"; 
  })
  .attr("r", "1px")
  .style("fill", function(d) { 
    return "black"//color(d.data.group); 
  });

 g.append("g")
    .attr("class", function(d,i) { 
    console.log("d", d)
    return "bubble"+i;//color(d.data.group); 
  })
  .attr("transform", function(d) {
        zones[d.data.group] = arc.centroid(d);
    return "translate(" + arc.centroid(d) + ")"; 
  })
  .attr("r", "1px")
  .style("fill", function(d) { 
    return "black"//color(d.data.group); 
  });


//create zone regions


//custom bubble chart
function makeBubbles(transform, group, radius){
    g.append("circle")
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
      return "translate("+transform+")"; 
    })
    .attr("r", radius)
    .style("stroke", function(d) { 
      return "black";//color(group); 
    })
    .style("fill", function(d) { 
      return color(group); 
    });
}


            function bubbledata(data){
      console.log("data", data)
                //loop through data -- and MERGE children
                var childs = [];
                $.each(data, function( index, value ) {
                    childs.push(value.children);                    
                });
                var merged = data;//[].concat.apply([], childs);//flatterns multidimensional array

                return $.extend(true, {}, {"children": merged});// return deep clone
            }


function setBubbleChart(width, index, data){

                  //_create bubble
                    var diameter = width/2;//take half/width

                    var bubs = svg.select(".bubble"+index).append("g")
                            .attr("class", "bubs");

                    bubs.attr("transform", "translate("+-diameter/2+","+-diameter/2+")");

                    var bubble = d3.layout.pack()
                      .size([diameter, diameter])
                      .value(function(d) {
                        return d.value;
                      })
                      .padding(3);

                  //_create bubble
          var data = bubbledata(data);

                        var nodes = bubble.nodes(data)
                          .filter(function(d) {
                             return !d.children;
                          }); // filter out the outer bubble


                        var bubbles = bubs.selectAll('circle')
                          .data(nodes);


                bubbles.enter()
                    .insert("circle")
                    .attr('transform', function (d) {
                        return 'translate(' + d.x + ',' + d.y + ')';
                    })
                    .attr('r', function (d) {
                        return d.r;
                    })
                    .style("fill", function (d) {
return color(d.group);
                    });

                bubbles = bubbles.transition()
                    .transition()
                    .duration(250)
                    .attr('transform', function(d) {
                        return 'translate(' + d.x + ',' + d.y + ')';
                    })
                    .attr('r', function (d) {
                        return d.r;
                    })
                    .ease('sine');

}



//loop through data and for EACH children array paint dots.
$.each(data, function( index, value ) {
setBubbleChart(100, index, value.children);


});    
//custom bubble chart    


function type(d) {
  d.value = +d.value;
  return d;
}
```

Comment: https://bl.ocks.org/d3indepth/c9fd848b9410cc543a437b34c266ac64

Comment: https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/c274877f647361f3df7d

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24170899/arc-centroid-returning-nan-nan-in-d3

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16062257/d3-js-donut-chart-arc-centroidd-is-not-influenced-by-d-innerradius-and-d-ou

Comment: https://gist.github.com/enjalot/1203641

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've plotted the mid-arcs - but they are not being updated on a change of data?

[image]
http://jsfiddle.net/Qh9X5/10066/

```
function change(data) {


  var slice = svg.select(".slices").selectAll("path.slice")
    .data(pie(data), key);

  slice.enter()
    .insert("path")
    .style("fill", function(d) {
      return color(d.data.label);
    })
    .attr("class", "slice");

  slice
    .transition().duration(1000)
    .attrTween("d", function(d) {
      this._current = this._current || d;
      var interpolate = d3.interpolate(this._current, d);
      this._current = interpolate(0);
      return function(t) {
        return arc(interpolate(t));
      };
    })

  slice.exit()
    .remove();



  var placeholders = svg.select(".placeholders").selectAll("circle.placeholder")
    .data(pie(data), key);

  placeholders.enter()
    .insert("circle")
    .style("fill", function(d) {
      return "white";
      //return color(d.data.label); 
    })
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
      return "translate(" + arc.centroid(d) + ")";
    })
    .attr("r", "5")
    .attr("class", "placeholder");

  placeholders
    .transition().duration(1000)

  placeholders.exit()
    .remove();   


};
```

---

[image]

I've managed to create an arc2 -- and animate the placeholders.

http://jsfiddle.net/Qh9X5/10068/

```
var svg = d3.select("#pies")
  .append("svg")
  .append("g")

svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "slices");
svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "placeholders");
svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "labels");
svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "lines");

var width = 560,
  height = 450,
  radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2;

var pie = d3.layout.pie()
  .sort(null)
  .value(function(d) {
    return d.value;
  });

var arc = d3.svg.arc()
  .outerRadius(radius * 0.85)
  .innerRadius(radius * 0.83);

var arc2 = d3.svg.arc()
    .outerRadius(radius - 10)
    .innerRadius(0);


var outerArc = d3.svg.arc()
  .innerRadius(radius * 0.9)
  .outerRadius(radius * 0.9);

svg.attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");

var key = function(d) {
  return d.data.label;
};

var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
  .domain(["Lorem ipsum", "dolor sit", "amet", "consectetur", "adipisicing"])
  .range(["#98abc5", "#8a89a6", "#7b6888", "#6b486b", "#a05d56"]);

function randomData() {
  var labels = color.domain();
  return labels.map(function(label) {
    return {
      label: label,
      value: Math.random()
    }
  });
}


console.log("randomData()", randomData());
change(randomData());

d3.select(".randomize")
  .on("click", function() {
    change(randomData());
  });


function change(data) {



  var slice = svg.select(".slices").selectAll("path.slice")
    .data(pie(data), key);

  slice.enter()
    .insert("path")
    .style("fill", function(d) {
      return color(d.data.label);
    })
    .attr("class", "slice");

  slice
    .transition().duration(1000)
    .attrTween("d", function(d) {
      this._current = this._current || d;
      var interpolate = d3.interpolate(this._current, d);
      this._current = interpolate(0);
      return function(t) {
        return arc(interpolate(t));
      };
    })

  slice.exit()
    .remove();




  var placeholders = svg.select(".placeholders").selectAll("circle.placeholder")
    .data(pie(data), key);

  placeholders.enter()
    .insert("circle")
    .style("fill", function(d) {
      return "white";
    })
    .attr("r", "5")
    .attr("class", "placeholder");


  placeholders
    .transition().duration(1000)
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
        console.log("arc.centroid(d)", arc2.centroid(d))
      return "translate(" + arc2.centroid(d) + ")";
    })

  placeholders.exit()
    .remove();



};
```

---

[image]

http://jsfiddle.net/Qh9X5/10075/

I have managed to merge the pie chart with the bubble chart -- if the data sets change - the animations should be stable.

```
var svg = d3.select("#pies")
  .append("svg")
  .append("g")

svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "slices");
svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "placeholders");


var width = 560,
  height = 450,
  radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2;

var pie = d3.layout.pie()
  .sort(null)
  .value(function(d) {
    return d.value;
  });

var arc = d3.svg.arc()
  .outerRadius(radius * 0.85)
  .innerRadius(radius * 0.83);

var arc2 = d3.svg.arc()
  .outerRadius(radius - 10)
  .innerRadius(0);

var outerArc = d3.svg.arc()
  .innerRadius(radius * 0.9)
  .outerRadius(radius * 0.9);

svg.attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");


function colores_google(n) {
  var colores_g = ["#f7b363", "#448875", "#c12f39", "#2b2d39", "#f8dd2f"];
  return colores_g[n % colores_g.length];
}



var data = [{
  "group": "<5",
  "value": 1000,
  "children": [{
    "group": "<5",
    "label": "Mel",
    "value": 1000,
    "totalGroupValue": 1000
  }]
}, {
  "group": "5-13",
  "value": 1000,
  "children": [{
    "group": "5-13",
    "label": "Erica",
    "value": 1000,
    "totalGroupValue": 1000
  }]
}, {
  "group": "14-17",
  "value": 2000,
  "children": [{
    "group": "14-17",
    "label": "Jessica",
    "value": 1500,
    "totalGroupValue": 2000
  }, {
    "group": "14-17",
    "label": "Jill",
    "value": 500,
    "totalGroupValue": 2000
  }]
}, {
  "group": "18-24",
  "value": 1300,
  "children": [{
    "group": "18-24",
    "label": "Jerry",
    "value": 500,
    "totalGroupValue": 1300
  }, {
    "group": "18-24",
    "label": "Ben",
    "value": 500,
    "totalGroupValue": 1300
  }, {
    "group": "18-24",
    "label": "Billy",
    "value": 300,
    "totalGroupValue": 1300
  }]
}, {
  "group": "25-44",
  "value": 1000,
  "children": [{
    "group": "25-44",
    "label": "Kelly",
    "value": 1000,
    "totalGroupValue": 1000
  }]
}];

$.each(data, function(index, value) {
  value["groupid"] = index;
  $.each(value.children, function(i, v) {
    v["groupid"] = index;
  });
});

//slices
var slice = svg.select(".slices").selectAll("path.slice")
  .data(pie(data));

slice.enter()
  .insert("path")
  .style("fill", function(d) {
    return colores_google(d.data.groupid);
  })
  .attr("class", "slice");

slice
  .transition().duration(1000)
  .attrTween("d", function(d) {
    this._current = this._current || d;
    var interpolate = d3.interpolate(this._current, d);
    this._current = interpolate(0);
    return function(t) {
      return arc(interpolate(t));
    };
  })

slice.exit()
  .remove();
//slices



//placeholder bubbles
var placeholders = svg.select(".placeholders").selectAll("g.placeholder")
  .data(pie(data));

placeholders.enter()
  .insert("g")
  .attr("class", function(d, i) {
    return "placeholder place" + i;
  });

placeholders
  .transition().duration(1000)
  .attr("transform", function(d) {
    return "translate(" + arc2.centroid(d) + ")";
  })

placeholders.exit()
  .remove();
//placeholder bubbles




//bubbles
function bubbledata(data) {
  //loop through data -- and MERGE children
  var childs = [];
  $.each(data, function(index, value) {
    childs.push(value.children);
  });

  return $.extend(true, {}, {
    "children": data
  }); // return deep clone
}


function setBubbleChart(width, index, data) {

  //_create bubble
  var diameter = width / 2; //take half/width

  var bubs = svg.select(".place" + index).append("g")
    .attr("class", "bubs");

  bubs.attr("transform", "translate(" + -diameter / 2 + "," + -diameter / 2 + ")");

  var bubble = d3.layout.pack()
    .size([diameter, diameter])
    .value(function(d) {
      return d.value;
    })
    .padding(3);

  //_create bubble
  var data = bubbledata(data);

  var nodes = bubble.nodes(data)
    .filter(function(d) {
      return !d.children;
    }); // filter out the outer bubble


  var bubbles = bubs.selectAll('circle')
    .data(nodes);

  bubbles.enter()
    .insert("circle")
    .attr('transform', function(d) {
      return 'translate(' + d.x + ',' + d.y + ')';
    })
    .attr('r', function(d) {
      return d.r;
    })
    .style("fill", function(d) {
      return colores_google(d.groupid);
    });

  bubbles = bubbles.transition()
    .transition()
    .duration(250)
    .attr('transform', function(d) {
      return 'translate(' + d.x + ',' + d.y + ')';
    })
    .attr('r', function(d) {
      return d.r;
    })
    .ease('sine');

}

//loop through data and for EACH children array paint dots.
$.each(data, function(index, value) {
  setBubbleChart(100, index, value.children);
});
//custom bubble chart
```